# Understanding SelectItemGroup

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, renderer, selectoneradio

Digging into the `RadioRenderer` source code I've noticed the following thing:

The method

```
@Override
protected void renderOption(FacesContext context,
                            UIComponent component,
                            Converter converter,
                            SelectItem curItem,
                            Object currentSelections,
                            Object[] submittedValues,
                            boolean alignVertical,
                            int itemNumber,
                            OptionComponentInfo optionInfo) throws IOException
```

overriden in the `RadioRenderer` class is being called from the standard  `public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component)` Renderer method. But there was the following piece of code:

```
Iterator<SelectItem> items =
          RenderKitUtils.getSelectItems(context, component);
//some code
while (items.hasNext()) {
        SelectItem curItem = items.next();
        idx++;
        // If we come across a group of options, render them as a nested
        // table.
        if (curItem instanceof SelectItemGroup) {
             // do some
        else {
             // do another
        }
}
```

So, I tried it by the example:

```
<h:selectOneRadio>
    <f:selectItem />
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.vals}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.valss}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

and the `selectItem` and the `selectItems`es were treated as not the instances of  the `SelectItemGroup`. For `selectItem` that's perfectly clear, but I expected that `selectItems` would be mapped to the `SelectItemGroup` instance.

Couldn't you clarify the thing a bit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can not declaratively be created. It can only programmatically be created. The `<f:selectItems>` also supports `List<SelectItem>` with [`javax.faces.model.SelectItem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html) instances of which the [`SelectItemGroup`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItemGroup.html) is a subclass. Below is an extract of relevance of its [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItemGroup.html):

> **SelectItemGroup** is a subclass of [`SelectItem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html) that identifies a set of options that will be made available as a subordinate "submenu" or "options list", depending upon the requirements of the [`UISelectMany`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UISelectMany.html) or [`UISelectOne`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UISelectOne.html) renderer that is actually used. In general, the value property of this instance will be ignored, and the label property of this instance will be used to label the submenu.

Here's a basic example of how you can create them:

```
private List<SelectItem> availableItems; // +getter

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    availableItems = new ArrayList<>();

    SelectItemGroup group1 = new SelectItemGroup("Group 1");
    group1.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[] {
        new SelectItem("Group 1 Value 1", "Group 1 Label 1"),
        new SelectItem("Group 1 Value 2", "Group 1 Label 2"),
        new SelectItem("Group 1 Value 3", "Group 1 Label 3")
    });
    availableItems.add(group1);

    SelectItemGroup group2 = new SelectItemGroup("Group 2");
    group2.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[] {
        new SelectItem("Group 2 Value 1", "Group 2 Label 1"),
        new SelectItem("Group 2 Value 2", "Group 2 Label 2"),
        new SelectItem("Group 2 Value 3", "Group 2 Label 3")
    });
    availableItems.add(group2);
}
```

```
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
```

---

Inside [`<h:selectOneRadio>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/selectOneRadio.html) it will render as a nested table (which is IMHO a poor rendering, they'd better have rendered the group label as a `<thead>`, but that aside). It's best visible when you set `layout` to `pageDirection`, otherwise everything will appear in a single line (`lineDirection`).

```
<h:selectOneRadio layout="pageDirection">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

[image: <h:selectOneRadio> with SelectItemGroup]

---

And inside the [`<h:selectOneMenu>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/selectOneMenu.html) it will render as a tree with option values nested in `<optgroup>` (which is actually the primary use case for `SelectItemGroup`):

```
<h:selectOneMenu>
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

[image: <h:selectOneMenu> with SelectItemGroup]

---

The [`<h:selectManyListbox>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/selectManyListbox.html) also supports it (the [`<h:selectOneListbox>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/selectOneListbox.html) has exactly the same rendering, but supports only a single selection):

```
<h:selectManyListbox>
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

[image: <h:selectManyListbox> with SelectItemGroup]

---

The [`<h:selectManyCheckbox>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/selectManyCheckbox.html) has the same (semantically awkward) nested table rendering as `<h:selectOneRadio>`:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox layout="pageDirection">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

[image: <h:selectManyCheckbox> with SelectItemGroup]

---

The [`<h:selectManyMenu>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/selectManyMenu.html) isn't useful at all, so I'll skip it.

#### See also:

- [Our `selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

Comment: JSF should also provided a declarative approach to be consistent with html `<optGroup>`. Optional they could provide a `groupBy` and `groupLabel` attribute, since a two level hierarchy is often sufficient.

Comment: thanks for the component. Always bet on OmniFaces :)